# http request and regex in Python for HTML parser

Tags: python, get, http.client

When I execute the script, the result is empty. Why? The script connected with a site and parse html tag `<a>`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re
import socket
import urllib, urllib.error
import http.client
import sys

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('www.guardaserie.online');
headers = { "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" }
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({"s":"hannibal"})
conn.request('GET', '/',params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse();

site = re.search('<a href="(.*)" class="box-link-serie">', str(response.read()), re.M|re.I)
if(site):
  print(site.group())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely the pattern you are searching for is non-existent in the read response, or it chokes at some point trying to parse html.

```
re.search( 'href="(.*)" class="box-link-serie"', str(response.read()), re.M | re.I )
```

Using something more generic or another parser method will likely lead you to your desired result.

Comment: If you tried the pattern above it should return a result. I would recommend you try using these imports: `import re, httplib, socket, urllib, sys`, and change `params = urllib.urlencode`, as well as `conn = httplib.HTTPConnection` ...

Comment: the pattern return the entire html page

Comment: the result is always that

Comment: I get `href="http://www.guardaserie.online/ray-donovan-a/" class="box-link-serie"` when using `print(site.group())` ... python code here : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/43026f7262b2fddfb7643169f0d558b2

Comment: [See comment #4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774213/http-request-and-regex-in-python/38774564?noredirect=1#comment64921304_38774564).

Comment: the result is always that

Comment: I solved the problem by using beautiful soap to make the parser

Comment: I believe you mean the second problem was solved by using beautiful soup instead. The first problem, which the original question asks about in regards to the blank output, was solved by my answer and suggestions.